# Convert rows of beautiful table to list

Tags: python, python-beautifultable

I would like to convert the rows of [beautifultable](https://beautifultable.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to elements of a list while excluding the header e.g:

```
 [['A',2,4], ['B',2,5], ['C',2,1]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call

`list(map(list, table))`

the full code:

```py
from beautifultable import BeautifulTable
table = BeautifulTable()
table.column_headers = ["c1", "c2", "c3"]
table.append_row(['A', 2, 4])
table.append_row(['B', 2, 5])
table.append_row(['C', 2, 6])
print(table)
# it will print
# +----+----+----+
# | c1 | c2 | c3 |
# +----+----+----+
# | A  | 2  | 4  |
# +----+----+----+
# | B  | 2  | 5  |
# +----+----+----+
# | C  | 2  | 6  |
# +----+----+----+
li = list(map(list, table))
print(li)
# it will print
# [['A', 2, 4], ['B', 2, 5], ['C', 2, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Beautifultable would give the following result if you try to get the rows:

```
    list([r for r in table])

 => [RowData<'A',2,4>, RowData<'B',2,5>, RowData<'C',2,1>]
```

To convert it to the form: `[['A',2,4], ['B',2,5], ['C',2,1]]`

Use:

```
list([list(r) for r in table])
```